# How do I get the current PyInterpreterState?

Tags: python, c, multithreading, python-c-api

I'd like to create a `PyThreadState` since there doesn't appear to be one for the current thread.

How do I get the current PyInterpreterState to pass to `PyThreadState_New(...)`, or is that something that I should only do if I'm embedding an interpreter (and thus have created it), rather than calling into a library from python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that not having a `PyThreadState` in the main thread is a fatal error. It was caused for me by two different python versions both being linked at the same time, so this question is somewhat moot.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you might are doing multi-threads programming. Recently, I'm having the similar problems. Hope the following codes may help you.

```c
//in main thread
PyThreadState * mainThreadState = NULL;

Py_Initialize();
PyEval_InitThreads();
mainThreadState = PyThreadState_Get();
PyEval_ReleaseLock();
```

```c
//in threaded thread
PyEval_AcquireLock();
PyInterpreterState * mainInterpreterState = mainThreadState->interp;
PyThreadState * myThreadState = PyThreadState_New(mainInterpreterState);
PyEval_ReleaseLock();
/*
 * embeded python part 
 * PyEval_CallObject() for example
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to call back into Python from a non-Python created thread, then you can use the PyGILState_Ensure() API. This takes care of creating a temporary thread state if the current thread doesn't already have one.

See http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads for more details.

Releasing the GIL in code that is called from a Python thread is even easier using the `Py_BEGIN(/END)_ALLOW_THREADS` macros:
http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#releasing-the-gil-from-extension-code

Comment: The problem is actually the reverse: calling from python into a library, during which time I want to allow other python threads to run.

Comment: In that case, you probably want the Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS and Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS macros: http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#releasing-the-gil-from-extension-code

Comment: These macros expand to calls to PyEval_SaveThread and PyEval_RestoreThread, which need a PyThreadState to exist for the current thread. It turns out that the fact I don't have a PyThreadState is, in fact, a fatal error.